# JQuery Ajax Post to MailForm.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, post

I want to go directly to my problem: My application shows data from an mysql database and the user can select those items and save them into an javascript list. After he has selected his items we want that he write his name in an inputfield and with the click on an button the "javascript-list" (contains only strings) should be send to our mailForm.php via post & ajax.

The problem is that our mailForm.php works perfectly fine (trying to access via Java and sending Post data) but we are not able to post the data via ajax and javascript (have a look:)

mailForm.php

```
<?
if ($_POST) {
    $message = "";
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_POST)) {
        if ($key == "mailAn") {
            $mymail = $val;
        } elseif ($key == "subject") {
            $subject = $val;
        } elseif ($key == "mailVon") {
            $email = $val;
        } elseif ($key == "message") {
            $message = $val;
        }
    }
    //array_walk ($_POST, "GetValues");
     if (mail($mymail,$subject,$message,"From: $email")) {
            header ("");
    } else {
        header ("Location: form_notok.htm");
        //echo "Fehler beim Senden des Formulars!";
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see wie have 4 keys (mailAn, subject, mailVon, message).. Any idea how this goes via js/jquery? (getting the Strings (javascriptlist) as message and the name (from inputfield) into mailVon)

Javascript:

```
$("#contact").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val(); //Inputfield with Name
  var email = $("#email").val(); // Inputfield with email
  var text = $("#text").val(); //should be list 
  var dataString = 'mailVon=' + name + '&mailAn=' + email + '&message=' + text;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./mailForm.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
      $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    }); 
  return false;
});
```

EDIT:
I now added the subject post param:

```
var dataString = 'mailVon=' + name + '&subject' + 'Test via javascript' + '&mailAn=' + email + '&message=' + text;
```

I still get an success message but no mail...

Comment: How are you posting the data with js?

Comment: added it in my questions - sorry. As you can see we are posting it via query ajax at the moment with a normal form (texfield,textfield,textarea) without the list - the problem: this should go well but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works perfectly fine - problem was the settings of the test host we used. Using our business webspace it will work. Good Look.

MailForm.php

```
<?
if ($_POST) {
    $message = "";
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_POST)) {
        if ($key == "mailAn") {
            $mymail = $val;
        } elseif ($key == "subject") {
            $subject = $val;
        } elseif ($key == "mailVon") {
            $email = $val;
        } elseif ($key == "message") {
            $message = $val;
        }
    }
    //array_walk ($_POST, "GetValues");
     if (mail($mymail,$subject,$message,"From: $email")) {
            header ("");
    } else {
        header ("Location: form_notok.htm");
        //echo "Fehler beim Senden des Formulars!";
    }
}
?>
```

JavaScript with fixed mail & javascript-list as dataString:

```
// Contact Form
$("#contact").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = 'your@email.com';
var message = '';
for (var i = 0; i < musicList.length; i++) {
    message += musicList[i];
    if(i < (musicList.lenght-1)){
        message += ', ';
    }
}
var dataString = 'mailVon=' + name + '&subject=' + 'Betreff: Music' + '&mailAn=' + email + '&message=' + message;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./mailForm.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(data) {
    if(data.status == 'success')
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
    else if(data.status == 'error')
        $('.error').fadeIn(1000);     
    }
}); 
return false;
});
```

Hope it will help someone else too

-Domi

Answer (score 1):

I would setup some echos and debug it with firebug.

```
    if (isset($_POST['mailAn'])){
    echo "Phase 1";
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
    switch ($key){
        case "mailAn":
            $mymail = $value;
            echo "Phase 2";
            break;
    }
    }
    }else{
        echo "FAILED";
    }
```

I would add headers to the mail function. 
       `

```
    <?
        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        // Additional headers
        $headers .= 'To: ' . $to . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Cc: ' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Bcc: ' . "\r\n";
        // Mail it
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

`

Comment: There is no bug in my PHP mailForm - if i send the post data via Java everything works great - the problem is in the javascript... :/

Comment: instead of var dataString = 'mailVon=' + name + '&mailAn=' + email + '&message=' + text; use var $data = $('#Form_Name').serialize(); Let jquery handle the data

Comment: But how should I parse these in my mailForm? the idname = paramname?

Comment: they would be the name. Are you setting your headers? Sometimes mail-servers will block "un-headered" mail.

Comment: okay, next problem with serialize() is that i have a list not only a form and so it would have no id for the paramname. My mailserver is open for every un-headered mails - no filters - as I told you, working perfectly with using java

Comment: Are you using a drop down list?

Comment: Found the problem^^ My testhoster doesn't allow the mail function - using the same code on my real webspace - everything worked perfect... thanks for the help anyway. I will give you an up vote for your help :)

Comment: O, that makes sense. especially if you an apache and friends setup on windows for testing..

Comment: never thought it would be a problem but yes... it was a problem :D